# What are suitable table names for a marketplace website's product catalog and active product listings?

Tags: naming

I am working on a project to develop an Amazon-style marketplace where users can sell their products on the website. One requirement is that users cannot sell anything but the products loaded into the database.

For example, an administrator can create the product "Star Wars T-Shirt," and at that moment, users can start selling that specific shirt.

So, I imagine that I need two tables: one for "parent products," which are not the ones buyers purchase but constitute the product catalog, and another table for the actual products that various sellers put up for sale. Something like "meta_products" and "products" with a one-to-many relationship, where one "meta_product" has many "products."

The question is, what names do you suggest for these two tables and relatives models? The name "products" or "articles" works fine for me, but I really don't like "meta_products" or "parent_products" at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use the following names: "products" and "listings".